# How does garena client sets up a network?

Tags: windows, vpn, packet-capture

How does Garena works ?? Does it work based on VPN ??? But it doesnot create any virtual network adapter. so how does it creates a network between players ??

One thing is for sure, garena client includes a game launcher. So I suppose when u start any multiplayer game like warcraft via the launcher, it somehow intercepts the packets to and from the warcraft game and send it to the destination via VPN or any other means (Tell me what means are possible for gaming over internet if not VPN)

But how can u do so ?? How can u intercept all packets from a particular application without using any virtual network adapter ? and what protocol could it be using to establish a lag-free gaming experience ??

Assume : windows, warcraft, internet, NAT, Lag free

Answer (score 2):

> How does Garena works ??

Last time I used it, GArena gets a list of servers (from a central location), and when you start a game (say CoD4) it lunches the game with the server:port as a parameter and since most of garena users are connecting to the same server, you may thinks that it's garena that is routing the packets to the proper application.

> How can u intercept all packets from a particular application without using any virtual network adapter ?

It's called packet sniffing, tools like Wireshark can help you analyse all the packet that are transferred through a network interface without creating a virtual network adapter.

Comment: +! but I am not talking about sniffing. It seems as if garena clients captures all packets from the game and modifies it to forward it to the computer where game server is hosted. So how to do that ?? Same is done by Lancraft or battle lan softwares. modifying a packet and sending it out is ok but when a packet is received from server how is garena client sending it back to the game without any network adapter ???

Comment: It does not do any of that. Games already contain the code for the multiplayer part of the game, they can connect to servers even without GArena (So it's not garena that is sending/routing the packets to the game server, but the games themselves. garena is just providing an address+port to connect to and the game does the rest) but unfortunately, most of the servers that you connect to through garena are cracked server.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that game must be started from withing Garena client. Maybe they reroute calls to Winsock library once the library is loaded.

I don't know how they did it, but I would do it with [layered service provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider).

Comment: did u mean dll inject and hook winsock method?

Comment: Feature called "layered service provider" is different from DLL injection. You can follow the link provided in the answer to learn more, but from 2012 this feature was deprecated (my answer was from 2011). Replacement feature is called [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page)